# MVC 4 app is not working properly on Windows 10?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, windows-10

My laptop was switched from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and Im doing MVC 4 development on it with VS 2012 Profesional. The problem is the after reinstallation the application in not stable on local machine. The problem are:

Behavior 1) while opening project in VS 2012 profesional error apears:

> ASP.NET 4.0has been not registred on the Web server. You need to
>   manuallyconfigure your Web Server for ASP.NET 4.0 in order to your
>   site work correctly

I tried `aspnet_regiis -i` but it gives

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>aspnet_regiis -i Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS w
>   wersji 4.0.30319.0 Administracyjny program narzędziowy do instalowania
>   i odinstalowywania platformy ASP.NET na komputerze lokalnym. Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation. Wszelkie prawa zastrzeżone. Rozpoczęto
>   instalowanie platformy ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0). Ta opcja jest
>   nieobsługiwana w tej wersji systemu operacyjnego. Administratorzy
>   powinni zainstalować/odinstalować program ASP.NET 4.5 z usługami IIS
>   8, używając okna dialogowego Włącz lub wyłącz funkcje systemu Windows,
>   narzędzia do zarządzania Menedżer serwera albo narzędzia wiersza
>   polecenia dism.exe. Aby uzyskać więcej szczegółowych informacji,
>   zobacz http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771. Zakończono
>   instalowanie platformy ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).

So I installed ASP.NET 4.5 but still error appears ..

Behavior 2) Application compiles properly and runs in debug mode but:) .... images are not displayed.
When I try to open one image directly like this `http://localhost:30246/Content/images/logo.svg` error appears:

Error Code:    0x800700b7

Description (transalted from polish):

> Cannot add duplicate entry for collection  with type  mimeMap” with
>   unique key value „fileExtension” set to „.json”

Code:

```
  112:     <staticContent>
  113:       <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  114:     </staticContent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix:)

I go to IIExpress configuration file  `C:\Users\XXX\Documents\IISExpress\configapplicationhost.xml` and commented out JSON entry:

```
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="application/javascript" />
     <!--   <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" /> -->
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".jsonld" mimeType="application/ld+json" />
```

Project still give warning while opening but it seems to work.